# Onclick button to delete a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, onclick

I wanted to delete a row in MySQL whenever the button is clicked, but everytime i run the code it already deletes the row before i even click the button.

index.ejs

```
  <button id="close" onclick="deleter()" id="X"> X </button>
```

server.js

```
con.connect(function deleter(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var sql = "DELETE FROM questionrecord WHERE QuestionID = '3'";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Number of records deleted: " + result.affectedRows);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `mysql` package, the `connect()` method takes a callback function that is supposed to handle errors, and will be called immediately after the connection is attempted (see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections). You probably want to create an endpoint for your deleting and call that using a form or link.